# PostgreSQL - timestamp results in 12-hour format but need 24-hour

Tags: postgresql

I am working on synchronisation between our database and CRM, and the CRM needs the data type to be `TIMESTAMP` but when I execute this simple query

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP
```

I'm getting:

```
2018-06-13 08:37:05.944909
2018-06-13 01:37:05.944909
```

I'm 5 hours behind UTC, but I expected the timestamp to return `2018-06-13 13:37:05.944909`

When `2018-06-13 01:37:05.944909` is inserted into the CRM it thinks it's 1:37AM and that of course messes up a lot of other stuff.

I know I could convert this using `TO_CHAR(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` but that will change the data type to `TEXT`, which I can't have.

Is there a way to force PostgreSQL to display timestamps in 24-hour format without losing the data type?

Answer (score 1):

Use the the_char() function to format your timestamp value through PSQL

```
select to_char(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from the_table
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a solution that does not return a string.